# Expand JSON array of object to record with PostgresQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to expand an array of object in JSON with PostgreSQL.

TABLE CONTACTS (id int, data json);

```
1, {'firstName': 'John', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'addresses': [{'street': '1 Heaven St.', city: 'Wonderland'}, {'street': '3 Hell St.', city: 'Scarycity'}] }
2, {'firstName': 'Shiv', 'lastName': 'Durham', 'addresses': [{'street': '1 Sugar St.', city: 'Sweet City'}] }
```

And I want to turn it into view as

```
contact_id|address                                        |
1         |{'street': '1 Heaven St.', city: 'Wonderland'} |
1         |{'street': '3 Hell St.', city: 'Scarycity'}    |
2         |{'street': '1 Sugar St.', city: 'Sweet City'}  |
```

I tried some native function but i failed to get wanted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  id as contact_id,
  json_array_elements(data->'addresses') as address
from contacts;
```